# WCF OperationContract WebInvoke POST data is null

Tags: c#, wcf, post

I've following `OperationContract` on my WCF Service; and I use `HttpContext.Current.Request.Form["param"]` to retrieve the submitted data.

```
 [OperationContract]
 [WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
 public string authenticateUser()
```

My service.svc file contains `<%@ ServiceHost Language="C#" Debug="true" Service="service.login" Factory="System.ServiceModel.Activation.WebScriptServiceHostFactory" %>`

And now POST parameters are shown as null. I've inspected the requests using fidler.

This method was working for me for weeks until I've migrated to VS 2012 (This is the only change I've made) and my hosted Azure application also works fine.

Is there is any other way that I can get POST data?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why don't you send in the post data as method parameters?

Comment: @Trent I cannot use UriTemplate as I am using `WebScriptServiceHostFactory`

Comment: I use WebServiceHostFactory and don't have that limitation

Comment: @Trent I use `WebScriptServiceHostFactory` to return `JSONP`

Comment: @Trent the error message is `Endpoints using 'UriTemplate' cannot be used with 'System.ServiceModel.Description.WebScriptEnablingBehavior'.`

Comment: Have you played around with Bare vs Wrapped for BodyStyle?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/20039/discussion-between-trent-and-libin-tk)

Answer (score 0):

2 thoughts on this one

1) why don't you pass in parameters for your method like this?

```
[OperationContract]
[WebInvoke(Method = "POST", ResponseFormat = WebMessageFormat.Json)]
public string authenticateUser(string param)
```

Or

2) If that isn't an option for you, I wonder if putting this attribute might enable the normal ASP.NET pipeline such that form variables are available

```
[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Allowed)]
```

Comment: I've `[AspNetCompatibilityRequirements(RequirementsMode = AspNetCompatibilityRequirementsMode.Required)]` for enabling ASP.NET session-state